# Unable to start "mongod", aborts immediately

Tags: mongodb, command-line, error-handling, server, terminal

i'm unable to start my mongo servers. When "mongod" is ran, it gives me a list of errors and then promptly aborts.

Here is the full list of errors it gives me...

```
> JacobBroughtonsMacbook:projects JacobBroughton$ mongod
2018-12-18T15:29:03.071-0500 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2018-12-18T15:29:03.082-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=18069 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=JacobBroughtonsMacbook.local
2018-12-18T15:29:03.082-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.3
2018-12-18T15:29:03.082-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 7ea530946fa7880364d88c8d8b6026bbc9ffa48c
2018-12-18T15:29:03.082-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2018-12-18T15:29:03.082-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2018-12-18T15:29:03.082-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2018-12-18T15:29:03.082-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2018-12-18T15:29:03.082-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2018-12-18T15:29:03.083-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2018-12-18T15:29:03.083-0500 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2018-12-18T15:29:03.083-0500 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=7680M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
2018-12-18T15:29:03.643-0500 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (13) [1545164943:643647][18069:0x1098fa5c0], wiredtiger_open: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: Permission denied Raw: [1545164943:643647][18069:0x1098fa5c0], wiredtiger_open: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: Permission denied
2018-12-18T15:29:03.643-0500 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (13) [1545164943:643942][18069:0x1098fa5c0], wiredtiger_open: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: Permission denied Raw: [1545164943:643942][18069:0x1098fa5c0], wiredtiger_open: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: Permission denied
2018-12-18T15:29:03.644-0500 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (13) [1545164943:644201][18069:0x1098fa5c0], wiredtiger_open: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: Permission denied Raw: [1545164943:644201][18069:0x1098fa5c0], wiredtiger_open: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: Permission denied
2018-12-18T15:29:03.644-0500 W STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to start up WiredTiger under any compatibility version.
2018-12-18T15:29:03.644-0500 F STORAGE  [initandlisten] Reason: 13: Permission denied
2018-12-18T15:29:03.644-0500 F -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28595 at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 645
2018-12-18T15:29:03.644-0500 F -        [initandlisten]
```

***aborting after fassert() failure

Any assistance with this would be extremely helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

FYI - I am running mongoDB locally on my macbook, installed via homebrew.

I had this issue after upgrading my macOS - I always end up with permissions issues in my web dev files after doing that.

No matter what I did, I could not seem to change the file permissions on my Macintosh HD/data/db folders to something mongod would use. However, `sudo mongod` did work. So the solution was:

1. Open Terminal
2. Run `sudo mongod`
3. Open a new Tab in Terminal
4. Run `mongodump` to export your databases into a folder (by default it is a folder called 'dump' in Macintosh HD/data/
5. Move this folder to your desktop, then delete Macintosh HD/data. Recreate data and data/db folders + check permissions
6. Quit Terminal
7. You should now be able to run `mongod` in a fresh Terminal window. Open a new Terminal tab and restore your databases with `mongorestore -d djsb /Users/<USER_NAME>/Desktop/dump`